# Kafka broker memory leak triggered by many consumers

Tags: java, memory-leaks, apache-kafka

I'm building a Java 8 application that queries a Kafka topic for exactly one message. Each request creates a new `Consumer` object (independent from any existing `Consumer` objects) which polls my Kafka topic, gets one record, and the `Consumer` is closed. This happens ~200k times per day and each request is independent of all others, so I don't think I can reuse consumers. Basically, a user requests a message from the topic and a consumer is created for them, then closed. This happens on average ~2 times per second, but is arbitrary, so it can happen 10 times/s or 1 time/hour, there's no way to know.

After a while, the heap size on the Kafka server (not the server running the code, but the actual server running Kafka) gets huge and garbage collection can't clear it. Eventually, more CPU time is dedicated to GC than anything else, and everything crashes until I restart Kafka.

Here's an approximate version of the code that's causing the issue, with a `while(true)` approximating real behaviour (in production, the consumers are not created in a while loop, but are created on-demand when a user requests a message from the topic):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "SERVER_IP:9092");
props.put("session.timeout.ms", 30000);
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", 1000);

while(true){
    Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("TOPIC", 0);
    consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(tp));
    consumer.seekToEnd(Arrays.asList(tp));

    // I've narrowed down the memory leak to this line
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> cr = consumer.poll(1000); 
    // If I remove this line ^, the memory leak does not happen

    /* CODE TO GET ONE RECORD */

    consumer.unsubscribe();
    consumer.close();
}
```

Running this code on 20 JVMs leads to a memory leak in about 20min. Here's what the heap (blue) and GC pause time (green) on the Kafka server look like:
[image: KafkaMemoryLeak]

Am I doing something wrong (or is there a better way to approach this), or is this a bug in Kafka when a lot of consumers are created and closed?

I'm running Kafka 0.10.2.1 on the client side and Kafka 0.10.2.0 on the server.

Comment: Creating a consumer is comparatively expensive. You're doing it over and over and over and over again.

Comment: @ftr Note that the heap consumption is on the server, and only creating the consumer does not create the leak. The polling part seems to creating the leak.

Comment: The brokers also have housekeeping to do for each new consumer.

Comment: @ftr If I remove the line that does the poll, the memory leak goes away, so you're right, but the broker deals with the housekeeping just fine if there's no poll (and with the expense of creating consumers). So it's not the ideal solution, but I still think there's a bug in Kafka when used the way I'm using it now.

Comment: @BogdanIstrate I have the feeling that it might be a side effect of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3489

Comment: I think the JMX metrics for each consumers never get removed / cleaned from the consumer map. That creates a leak over time. Command to check the number of consumer entries with JMX : echo -e  "open $(pgrep -f kafkaServer)\nbeans\n" | java -jar ~/Downloads/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar   | grep client-id=consumer | wc -l
```

Comment: have you determined the cause of this issue?

Comment: Thank-you Tony, you are correct re: consumer leak related to jmx metrics. Ticket has been raised here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9504?jql=project%20%3D%20KAFKA%20AND%20text%20~%20%22Consumer%20Leak%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the number and frequency of requests you receive, you can still reuse KafkaConsumer instances. You can only poll when a request arrives, but you don't need to create and close a consumer each time.

Having said that, your usage of the consumers might have revealed a memory management issue on the broker if memory usage increases and is not reclaimed by GCs. I have seen issues reporting the broker runs out of direct memory when the producers are recycled very frequently. So it's likely there is scope for improvement there. Probably best to raise a ticket at issues.apache.org to have it looked at.

Answer (score 0):

You are polling Kafka ~200k times per day i.e. ~8k times an hour/~140 times per minute/~twice every second - why are you creating (and closing) a new instance of the consumer every time ? Just schedule the `KafkaConsumer` to trigger as per your required interval (you can use a JDK `ScheduledExecutorService` for this) and reuse the same consumer instance

Comment: I edited the question to explain a bit better: in production, I have no control over when the requests happen (2/sec, 100/s, 1/hour). The while loop is only to replicate the behaviour and the memory leak. I might try a different approach, but I still think there's a bug in Kafka when used the way I'm using it now.

Comment: Can't comment about the 'kafka bug' part to be honest. I do realize that the while loop was for simulating the behavior and the fact that you dont have control over the production setting. But what I still dont understand is the part 'each request is independent of all others, so I don't think I can reuse consumers' - this is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka 2.4.0 (and likely previous versions) has a resource leak where some MBeans are not de-registered on Consumer.close().

It may be that this was the case when you originally asked the question, certainly Tony suggests this as the cause in comments to your question, above.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9504?jql=project%20%3D%20KAFKA%20AND%20text%20~%20%22Consumer%20Leak%22